# Query Optimizer/rewriter in Sesame and Jena

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, sesame

I run the following query on Sesame and Jena.

```
SELECT ?x ?y
{ ?x p1+ ?y .
?x p2/p3 ?z .
?y p2/p3 ?z .
FILTER(?x=<http://article.com/1-3> && ?y=<http://article.com/1-1> && not exists {
?k p1 ?x }
```

) }

To evaluate these queries on Jena, it always take more than 10 seconds on the files between 50 and 200MB.

Whereas in Sesame, it never takes more than 0.3 second. Could query rewriting be the reason?

When I rewrite the query as follows, it takes also about 0.5 seconds to evaluate the query in Jena:

```
select ?x ?y {
values(?x ?y){(<http://article.com/1-3> <http://article.com/1-1>)} 
?z ^(p2/p3) ?x, ?y .
?x p1+ ?y .
}
```

In Sesame, i use the following line:

```
TupleQuery tupleQuery = 
    con.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, selectQuery);
```

whereas in Jena, the following:

```
    DatasetGraph dsg = DatasetGraphFactory.create(g);
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
    Dataset ds = DatasetFactory.create(dsg);
    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, ds);
```

Comment: The rewritten query does not look like the first, the property path closure `+` is missing on `p1`.

Comment: Sorry, it was a type mistake here in stackoverflow, not mistake in the original query.

Comment: Ok, but 1) in the second query the `NOT EXISTS` part is missing. And 2) in the first query, the closing brace of the filter is wrong placed.

Comment: Nevertheless, if I assume that the second query contains everything from the first, it's interesting but not uncommon. Did you check what Jena uses as optimized query? What happens if you change the order of the two triple patterns in the second query?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the filter. Not Exists make the first query more efficient, so it is not a problem.

Comment: I haven't changed the order of triples in the second query. How can i check what Jena or Sesame use as optimized query?

Comment: You have changed the order of the triples. You put "?x p1+ ?y ." later. Also the storage can make a difference. As can the version of Apache Jena.

Comment: Apache Jena is missing an optimization -- see JENA-1190. The VALUES version captures the possibility. You should be able to put "?x p1+ ?y . "before "?z ^(p2/p3) ?x, ?y ."

Comment: I used Jena ARQ 2.12.1 . As for the storage, from the code it is clear which type of graph store i use.